# UICollectionView, Scroll to a cell not on screen

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a collectionview showing cells based on a 1000+ datasource.
the collectionview at any given time shows 6 cells. Now based on some user action I need to scroll the collectionview to another NSIndexPath but when I try to do that

```
  [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
                                   animated:NO];
```

I get this error :

```
   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
   'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath 0x11b42e70> 2 indexes [1, 163]'
```

I assume this error is happening because that indexpath is not on the screen, or hasn't been loaded yet.

two issues :

1 : Is my assumption correct? or is this error something else?
2 : If my assumption is correct,what can I do to fix it ??:)

Thanks

Comment: Your assumption is not correct.  Are you trying to scroll to section 1 (which is the *second* section) in a collection view that only has 1 section?  Can you also add how `newIndexPath` is created?

Comment: dude, u got it, I changed it to section 0, that was it. thanks.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so this question doesn't get marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section you are scrolling to doesn't exist in the collection view.  If you are intending to scroll to the first section, remember they are indexed from 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any section but you do not have defined section remove section code.

I used `var selectedIndexPath = IndexPath(index: 0, section: 0)`

I just removed `section` and it works!